# How to refresh a patch variable after tick?

Tags: loops, netlogo

I have a patch variable X which i want to be computed after each tick. I basically have a condition where at each tick i want to highlight only those patches whose X value is greater than the limit that i have placed.

This is what i have coded:

```
ask patches with [votes-with-benefit > 0] [ ifelse (b-c <= threshold) 
     [ set votes-with-benefit 0 set pcolor red ]
     [ set votes-with-benefit votes
       set pcolor scale-color white vote-share 0 max-voteshare ]
   ]
```

The problem is after the first tick even though there are patches who value is greater than the threshold they still appear red instead of reverting back to white.

Thanks in adavance. Appreciate the help.

Regards

Comment: where does this code get called from? Are other patches becoming red each tick?

Comment: This code gets called at both the Set & Go stage. At time 0 those patches whose b-c value is < threshold becomes red. b-c is measured at each tick. b-c is a sum of two other patch-level metrics. So after Go when the ticks start, while the b-c value changes with each tick, the initial patches which turned red never go back to white even though their b-c value is greater than the threshold. Where do you suppose the problem is?

Comment: hello, i figured it out. Sorry to have spammed. The patch variable was not updating after each tick because of two counter arguments i coded one after the other using two different 'ask patches command'. Once i combined them into one statement it started working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out. Sorry to have spammed. The patch variable was not updating after each tick because of two counter arguments i coded one after the other using two different 'ask patches command'. Once i combined them into one statement it started working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to switch the filter and the condition:

```
ask patches with [b-c <= threshold] [ ifelse  (votes-with-benefit > 0)
     [ set votes-with-benefit 0 set pcolor red ]
     [ set votes-with-benefit votes
       set pcolor scale-color white vote-share 0 max-voteshare ]
   ]
```

In any case, as you have it now, you will never reset those whose vote-with-benefits you set to zero, because you filter them out.